# How to create PS alias for EXE with many path parameters?

Tags: powershell, command-line

Why such alias doesn't work? In my opinion there is problem with duplicated quotation marks.

> New-Alias     -Name "chrome"  -Value ""C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --user-data-dir="%APPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data" --disk-cache-dir="%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data""

Comment: Aliases in PowerShell don't allow parameters.  They are simply alternate names for an existing command.  If you need parameters you'll need to use functions.  More info: [about_Aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to @boxdog's comment, [pointing to the alias documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-5.1), you must point your alias to a function if you want parameters.

Consider adding this to your `$profile` to accomplish your goal:

```
function Start-Chrome {
    $argList = @(
        "--user-data-dir=`"$Env:AppData\Google\Chrome\User Data`""
        "--disk-cache-dir=`"$Env:LocalAppData\Google\Chrome\User Data`""
    )
    & "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" @argList
}
New-Alias -Name chrome -Value Start-Chrome
```